# Where clause in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

How do I express this in NHibernate?

```
DECLARE @EntityId INT = 800;

SELECT *
FROM UserAlert
WHERE UserAlertId =  
                  (
                   SELECT MAX(UserAlertId)
                   FROM UserAlert
                   WHERE EntityId = @EntityId
                  )
```

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
var senderUA = session.CreateCriteria<UserAlert>()
                      .Add(Restrictions.Eq("EntityId", id))
                      .SetProjection( Projections.Max("Id") )
                      . UniqueResult();
```

And I keep getting an error that can convert object to UserAlert type, i.e. it's not even compiling.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

Ordering by UserAlertId descending and selecting top 1 would be simpler.

```
var senderUA = session.CreateCriteria<UserAlert>()
                  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("EntityId", id))
                  .AddOrder(Order.Desc("UserAlertId"))
                  .SetMaxResults(1)
                  .UniqueResult();
```

Additionally you can

```
var senderUA = session
                    .Query<UserAlert>()
                    .Where(x=>x.EntityId==id && 
                         x.UserAlertId==session.Query<UserAlert>()
                                           .Where(x=>x.EntiryId==id).Max(x=>x.UserAlertId)
                          ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `QueryOver`.

```
var maxUserAlertId = QueryOver.Of<UserAlert>
                             .Where(ua => ua.EntityId == id)
                             .Select(
                                 Projections.Max(
                                    Projections.Property<UserAlert>
                                                      (u => u.UserAlertId)
                                 )
                               );
var maxUserQuery = session
                     .QueryOver<UserAlert>()
                     .WithSubquery
                         .WhereProperty(u => u.EntityId)
                         .Eq(maxUserAlertId);

// Dealing with the situation that the maximum value is shared
// by more than one row. If you're certain that it can only
// be one, call SingleOrDefault instead of List
IList<UserAlert> results = maxUserQuery.List();
```