# A way to query without multiple DB calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

On a web-app I'm working on it using`NHibernate with ASP.NET-MVC`, we were experiencing some major lag on page loads, so I was given the task to look into it and do some refactoring.

When I looked through the code, there were many calls like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetAllClients()
{
    return new EntityManager<Client>()
        .GetAll<Client>()
        .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false || x.IsDeleted == null);
 }
```

After some debugging and searching I found out that this actually performs 2 separate calls to the database, one to `GetAll` then it applies the `Where` and does a second call, or something like that. I found another question on SO which made me decide to use a session instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetAllClients()
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionFactoryManager.Factory.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.QueryOver<Client>()
            .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false || x.IsDeleted == null)
            .List();
    }
}
```

this was a lot nicer as it took the `Where` clause into consideration before going to the database. However, there are still methods that I see calling `GetAll()` but then applying another `Where` on top of that:

```
var Clients = GetAllClients().Where(n => n.Location == "someCity");
```

My guess is this first calls the `GetAll()` using the session, then it applies the new `Where` and goes back to the database again? Is this true?

is there a better/more elegant way to do this?

Comment: What is the return type of GetAll?

Comment: its up there in the question, `IEnumerable`

Comment: I mean `GetAll` of `EntityManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very common problem when you **over abstract** the data access.

The `List` method call in `GetAllClients` method will cause all client records being loaded into memory from database.

I would suggest using one NHibernate `ISession` per request, instead of one `ISession` per method call. And make your methods returning `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`. Something like this (NHibernate 3.0+):

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Linq;

public class EntityManager<T> {
    private ISession _session;

    public EntityManager(ISession session) {
        _session = session;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAllClients() {
        return _session.Query<T>();
    }
}
```

Then you can filter by country:

```
GetAllClients().Where(it => it.Location == "city").ToList();
```

Or doing projection:

```
var clientShortInfos = GetAllClients().Where(it => it.Location == "city")
                                      .Select(it => new 
                                      {
                                           Id = it.Id,
                                           FullName = it.FullName
                                      })
                                      .ToList();
```

This allows you to retrieve only needed fields instead of all fields from database.

**Here are some helpful posts:**

- http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton
- http://ayende.com/blog/4101/do-you-need-a-framework

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is the result type of `GetAll` of `EntityManager`. If it is `IQueryable<Clinet>` then the where will be applied before hitting the database, if it is `IEnumerable<Client>`, or list, or array then `Where` will be performed in memory.

Because `GetAllClients` returns `IEnumerable<Client>` the subsequent calls to `Where` will be performed in memory.

Also, in the second example you probably want to use `Query` (Linq) instead of `QueryOver`. Linq and QueryOver are different query engines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You absolutely made correct solution. I don't know much about NHibernate but this case resembles with Entity Framework as well. Using session will avoid hit on server and prepare a query first. Once query is prepared then it will hit server.

You can also find an example of same where clause in NHibernate over here

[Where clause in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527700/where-clause-in-nhibernate)

You can also find a good tutorial related to IQueryable concept in Nhibernate over here.

http://ayende.com/blog/2227/implementing-linq-for-nhibernate-a-how-to-guide-part-1